# can't get the exact position in Map

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-maps, maps

Goal:
Get exactly position in Maps (google map) from my Galaxy SII

Problem:
I don't get the exact position in Maps from where I'm standing.

Comment: It is not clear whether the Google Maps gets its location from GPS or from WiFi or from GSM tower. If your device does not get location info from GPS, it will look for known WiFi and finally resorts to CellId from the tower. The accuracy of your location decreases drastically from former to the latter. Can you ensure you had switched on your GPS? And are your device seeing a clear sky to pick up the satellites?

Comment: I often have clear sky and I always use GPS then WiFi. From my experience I get more accurate position by WiFi.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to get decent GPS position inside buildings or covered areas. Try going outside; you'll get faster GPS locks.

Don't worry, you're not alone. I have the same problem.

Check out FasterFix / FasterGPS as well. They can help improve your GPS locks.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter If I'm located inside or outside.

Comment: @Legato Did you just buy the phone recently? Did it happen before, or only now?

Comment: I got SII by a friend. I hade it for 2 month and my friend had it for 4 month. When I got it in my hand, it didn't give any accurate data.

Comment: @Legato Maybe he sold it to you with "hidden defects"? Have you tried upgrading your Android [currently 4.0.3, but there's also 4.0.4 in certain countries], and see if it improves your GPS?